# Stack Navigator not showing the screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

So I've been trying to get the stack navigator to work. According to the console.log('Main') I do actually enter the main screen. Which is what I want. However, the screen just gives me a blank screen with only the header showing. I have no idea what the issue is. I thought it could be with the styling but I've deleted and changed it and nothing seems to be working as well. How I have been navigating was simply doing < ScreenName />. But that won't work because I'm trying to navigate around with buttons as well. 
 [Screenshot of login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4nJI.png)
[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqlt1.png)

```
App.js
  renderComponent() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      return (
        <Container />
        )
    } else {
      return (
        <LoginForm />
      )
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Header title='InTouch' />
        {this.renderComponent()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}


Screen Container
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Main from './src/components/Main'
import Upload from './src/components/Upload'

const NavigationStack = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: Main },
    Upload: {screen: Upload},

},{
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled:false
    }
})

const Container = createAppContainer(NavigationStack);

export default Container; 


Main.js

export default class Main extends Component<Props> {
    state = { currentUser: null}

  componentDidMount() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()

    this.setState({ currentUser })
  }
  render() {
    console.log("Main")
    const { currentUser } = this.state

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Hello</Text>
          <Button title = "Go to upload story" onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Upload')} />
          <Button
          title="Sign out"
          onPress={() => firebase.auth().signOut()} />
        </View>
      );
```

I just want the Main to show up.

Comment: the provided code should work, can you show us a screenshot of the app?

Comment: I just added it. Thank you.

Comment: Hey try add View style = {{flex:1}}.May be that will help.Put some other style too.

Comment: To where exactly? In Main? Or in the screen container?

Comment: In screen container. Set some background color too,that will help you debug find your error.

Answer (score 0):

Login screen should be under the stack navigation, and after logging in you can navigate to other screen

try doing it like this

```
const NavigationStack = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {screen: Login }
    Main: {screen: Main },
    Upload: {screen: Upload},

},{
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled:false
    }
})
```

alternatively you can create separate navigation for login and other screens using switch

```
const HomeNavigation = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: Main },
    Upload: {screen: Upload},

},{
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled:false
    }
})

const RootNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
    Login: {screen: Login }
    Home: {screen: HomeNavigation }
});
```

and in App.js do

```
  render() {
    return (
      <RootNavigation/>
    );
  }
```